# Inserting by passing an array of columns and an array of values in variables with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
q="INSERT INTO customers (?) VALUES (?)"
```

and I'm trying to pass the first placeholder an array of column names and the second placeholder an array of values, like so:

```
columns_arr = [
  'stat',
  'idcustomers',
  'parent_id',
  'cust_prio_code',
  'custadd_type_code',
  'customername',
  'EMAIL',
  'priority_id'
]
values_arr = [
  2,
  300,
  900,
  10003999,
  'someType',
  'dave',
  'mail@mail.com',
  99
]
var inserts = [columns_arr, values_arr]
var format_query = mysql.format(q, inserts)
mydb.query(format_query)
```

but the query that ends up being executed is:

```
INSERT INTO `customers` ('stat', 'idcustomers', 'parent_id', 'cust_prio_code', 'custadd_type_code', 'customername', 'EMAIL', 'priority_id') VALUES (2, 300, 900, 10003999, 'someType', 'dave', 'mail@mail.com', 99)
```

and it gives a syntax error:

(node:18776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''stat', 'idcustomers', 'parent_id', 'cust_prio_code', 'custadd_type_code', 'c...' at line 1

So, column names are being passed as strings. How can I solve it? I get this array dynamically, as it is, and so I can't just manually change it to an array without quotes, and even if I could it wouldn't compile as these are not declared in the code. trying to use `replace(/'/g,'')` didn't help. How can I pass this array to the query without the single quotes on each column name?

and if it's not the problem then what is?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales sure, I added it to the question

Comment: Have you ever tried removing the parenthesis in the query? `INSERT INTO customers ? VALUES ?`

Comment: 1) you cannot used prepared statement parameters to pass table or field names, only values. Use string concatenation with white list. 2) you have to have a parameter for each value you pass.

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales I have... it formats the query without parenthesis and gives a syntax error similar to the original one

Comment: @Shadow 1) so how can I achieve the same effect? can I use string manipulation? 2) what do you mean by that? a corresponding value for each parameter? I do have it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placeholders `?` in prepared statement are wrapped with single quotes. So your column names are treated as string literals, not as column names. And the query fails.

You must use `??` escaping placeholders.

```
q="INSERT INTO customers (??) VALUES (?)"
```

See [Escaping query identifiers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers).